# Generic type in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I write a custom hook for handle input in my app. I use generic type to define what type return for my custom hook. Here is my code

```
interface IUseInput<T, U> {
    (): [T, (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void, U];
}

function useInput<T, U>(): IUseInput<T, U> {
    const [input, setInput] = useState({});
    const [isDirty, setDirty] = useState({});

    const handleInputChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setInput({
            ...input,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
        setDirty({
            ...isDirty,
            [e.target.name]: true
        });
    };

    return [input, handleInputChange, isDirty] //this line get error
}


const Component: React.FC = () => {
    const [input, handleChangeInput, isDirty] = useInput<{username: string, password: string}, {username: boolean, password: boolean}>();

  return (
      ....
  )

}
```

But I get this error `Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'IUseInput<T, U>`

WHere is my wrong? Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IUseInput<T, U>` is the type of the function, not the type of the return type. There is no way to specify the type of a function declaration, only the type of a variable (to which you could assign a function). However this is not really necessary, I would just move the return type from `IUseInput` to the function declarartion.

An improvement that could be made, since `U` should have the same keys as `T` you can derive `U` from `T` using the predefined mapped type `Record`. So you can replace `U` with `Record<keyof T, boolean>`:

```
function useInput<T>(): [T, (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void, Record<keyof T, boolean>] {
    const [input, setInput] = useState({} as T);
    const [isDirty, setDirty] = useState({} as Record<keyof T, boolean>);

    const handleInputChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setInput({
            ...input,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
        setDirty({
            ...isDirty,
            [e.target.name]: true
        });
    };

    return [input, handleInputChange, isDirty] 
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=26&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxLYDCAFigHYDmSAogG5IPwC+cAZlAgg4AciioMogLAAoOf3wMMwCAwLEAkgzD4YAHgAqAPgAUASgBccANqHsppNbqMWHLgYAShgLIAZbV0YVgAbJBAPY3M4AF5jOHYIYAATbGQ0aGT9AGskAE8Ifjh7OAAjCAgwxmMAXVw5OEa4DIZCeBtgHT1sYhhAvTqYjVJySlMcPhRCYvMAbgamlrbbYEIAEWBYPJ6kGA2tweGyCiRxyen0zJz8wuLscsrUBij5+Vkm5rVl+gZksP6YC5mEhYnBHM4fm5ONx9N5-ADQuFItE4vV3h8mr0AeMFhiMQA6QmdIKYXF4po2JD48hQFgwfEMFARGrWKk0un49goEL4JBkj48Ob8zG7fYwPI49HkpqE-GrMXbYV4ynUlC03YMplIFlwGBQXlKuCC14C15kiQwfBQdQdLpYOA-P5IAFAljYeWbcV1OQ8OR+2RLeDUYSQBgeazIdD0gBi1FBFli8RwZMDKzt2EdYVdzvTcA9B1BRBzQX0OCL1q11jaUE6TGwYCmhAA7pkq3razwzEK3o0LVb1HAGPgQiEAIQ+oA)